# Scraping user profile and sorting

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

Hello I am scraping website that has some data stored in its header and paragraph tags
like this

```
<h2>Name</h2>
<p>example</p>
<p>example</p>
<p>example</p>
<p>example</p>
<p>example</p>
<p>example</p>
----
<h2>Name</h2>
.....
```

what i want to do is print all the information in these tags
which i kinda got succeed in doing 
here's my code

```
for h2 in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h2'):
    print (h2.text)
for p in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('p'):
    print (p.text)
    print ('---------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
driver.quit()
```

when i run this code i get all the p tags printed like this

```
names
a
b 
c
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Age
66 years old
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Gender
Male
```

But what i want is that it print name and then info of that person and then another name and it goes on my script just pump out all name first and then 
print info so its get hard to match the data with the same person
thats how i want it to run like

```
name 
a 
info 
info 
info
------------
name 
b
...
...
```

How can i solve this problem

EDIT:
was able to print them together by using div xpath

```
temp = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="v-b"]').text
time.sleep(1)
print (temp)
just lacking a separator now like this
```

```
name 
a 
info 
info 
info
------------
name 
b
...
...
```

Comment: Cannot add separator in between because temp will contains whole chunk of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below:

```
for h2 in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h2'):
    print (h2.text)
    for p in h2.find_elements_by_xpath(".//parent::div/p"):
        print (p.text)
    print ('---------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
driver.quit()
```

Comment: thank for you for replying but unfortunately it didn't worked it just print names and ends

Comment: my answer is incorrect, <h2>name</h2><p>info1</p><p>info2</p> .is the h2 and p contained in some other tag. then you can iterate over that tag. Could you share the exact html of the page

Comment: Updated the answer. In xpath we have option to navigate back to parent element of given xpath. So whatever name we have we can go back to the parent div and find the <p> tags which are contained in that div

Comment: i have edited my question i was able to print them together using xpath only lacking seperator now

Comment: check if the updated code is working. it should work

Answer (score 0):

First get the list and then iterate, try this code -

```
h2s = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h2')
for h2 in h2s:
    print(h2)

ps = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('p')
for p in ps:
    print(p)
```

Comment: thank for you for replying but unfortunately it didn't worked it just did the same thing that my code is doing